# Unable to access IDempiere - java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 123000/123000 ms

Tags: java, jetty, idempiere

I am Unable to access IDempiere Instance webui getting below error.

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 123000/123000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:436)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.WpdExtendlet.service(WpdExtendlet.java:104)
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web0(ClassWebResource.java:585)
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web(ClassWebResource.java:571)
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.service(ClassWebResource.java:262)
        at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:427)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 123000/123000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Request idle timed out at 123000 ms.

That means there was no activity (read or write) for 123000 ms and the connection was closed.